# Disaabe rule by ID in modsecurity on apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, mod-security

I put ModSecurity for a web server and works fine. But some of the cases it blocked and giving `Access Denied` page. Below shows unwanted rule IDs which are getting from after reading log file.

`950109 950901 958291 960024 973338 981172 981173 981231 981242 981243 981245 981246 981248 981257 981260 981318 981319 981320`

Some of the article says those IDs are `frequent false positives`. So I want to disable those IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching, I found a solution for disable those rule IDs. This is how I disable those IDs.

Add this on end of the `/etc/apache2/mods-available/security2.conf`

`<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleRemoveById 950109
    SecRuleRemoveById 950901
    SecRuleRemoveById 958291
    SecRuleRemoveById 960024
    SecRuleRemoveById 973338
    SecRuleRemoveById 981172
    SecRuleRemoveById 981173
    SecRuleRemoveById 981231
    SecRuleRemoveById 981242
    SecRuleRemoveById 981243
    SecRuleRemoveById 981245
    SecRuleRemoveById 981246
    SecRuleRemoveById 981248
    SecRuleRemoveById 981257
    SecRuleRemoveById 981260
    SecRuleRemoveById 981318
    SecRuleRemoveById 981319
    SecRuleRemoveById 981320
</IfModule>`

then restart apache. `service apache2 restart` .Now its working fine.

This can also type in a one line.

`<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleRemoveById 950109 950901 958291 960024 973338 981172 981173 981231    981242 981243 981245 981246 981248 981257 981260 981318 981319 981320
</IfModule>`

Comment: It's usually a good idea to disable security things only where needed, say on specific URLs, like in this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/1141194/50874 (that example uses Tag instead of Id for rule removal, but the principle is the same).

Answer (score 1):

That is a valid approach, but a bit coarse. The tutorials at https://netnea.com/apache-tutorials explain the details.

Besides, you are using an outdated version of the Core Rule Set. You should go and check out https://coreruleset.org. Update to CRS3 and 90% of your false positives will be gone.